# Using foreign key in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some Articles, each with a 'show' page. I am making it so each Article has some comments on the show page as well. I have a 'create' action for Comments, but I need to add a 'redirect' to the 'create' action of the Comments Controller.

I want the redirect to go to the show page of the Article to which the newly created Comment belongs.

How would I write this redirect_to statement?

Here's what I have so far:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    @article = ?________?
    redirect_to @article
  end
end
```

I appreciate your help because I have been befuddled by this concept for ages and really look forward to getting past this hump.

Comment: Have you tried `redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)`?

Comment: I don't see in your sample where you fetch the article. Is this a param you're passing or are you rendering this after fetching it somewhere else?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's what I'm trying to figure out (how to fetch the right article). I will try your method, but I have to construct a comments form first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your relationships are set up properly and your routes are defined properly, this is an extremely simple task.

Your models should be (at minimum):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

This ensures the proper helper methods on each model. Now define your routes so comments belong to an article:

```
// somewhere in routes.rb
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

This will give you nested routes, most notable the desired create route:

```
POST /articles/:article_id/comments
```

Which is where you direct your comment creations, your create will now look like:

```
// Comments controller
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id]) # Probably should verify this gets something
  if @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And that should solve you issue. (If there are any syntax issues or other confusions please let me know - this was pulled all from memory).

Comment: I would like to test this, but I'm not sure what url to put in the comment creation form. I have this route: `POST  /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)  comments#create` and I tried copying and pasting the second part, but got a "no route exists" error. I know this seems rather simple but I've really been stuck here for like 2 weeks, so I appreciate help immensely. I even trid using a named route for the aformentioned route but it didn't work either (tried `post '/articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)', to: 'comments#create', as: 'create_comment'`, and `:url => 'create_comment_path' `

Comment: @macsplean It sounds like your routes file is in need of some work beyond this question. I'm not sure what you mean by "what URL to put in comment creation form" since you shouldn't be using URLs if you're using the standard rails mechanisms. Your `new` action should contains a `@article = Article.find(params[:article_id]); @comment = @article.comments.new` and then your `form_for @comment, # etc...` (or maybe `form_for [@article, @comment], # etc...`) should handle routing itself.

Comment: @macsplean Don't use a named route, I gave you the exact two lines you need in your routes to get all the RESTful routes you'll need for articles and comments. The `resources` function is there for that exact purpose. Named routes are for non-RESTful routes that your application may need. If you want to use rails, don't fight rails.

Comment: I see. I actually wasn't using a new page. I was putting the comments page on the show page of the Article. Your advice has been helpful, though. I didn't realize there was no need to use URLs. I will make a route for POST from the page I put the form on.

Comment: Believe me, I'm not trying to fight rails, just understand it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with embedding the comments create form in the page for the Article. You still will need a create path (properly nested makes things really easy) for creating and redirecting properly. That just means the previous snippet I said should be in the Comments `new` action should instead be in the Article's `show` action (you're already getting an article, so create an empty comment for the form).

Comment: The article_id value is not getting submitted with the new comment.

Comment: I'm just gonna go back to the tutorial again. This obviously isn't as simple as you're making it out to be.

Comment: I guarantee you it is this simple, I write rails applications professionally. Good luck though!

Comment: @macsplean [Here](https://github.com/bbuck/simple_example) is an example application on Github that you can review the source code on. Fork it, steal it, use it, change it. I don't care, I hope that it does provide some insight into how simple this is. Specifically focus on the views, the controllers and the config/routes.rb file. If you have any more specific questions please contact me via the email which can be found on Github.